# the software Ns2.28 installed on ubuntu10.04

Tags: c++, gcc, ns2

when I install Ns2.28 on ubuntun10.04(64 bit), there are some errors.
The first error is the version of gcc. The install file in the folder which is in ns2.28-allinone set the version of gcc as 3.4.I set the version the number of my gccc which is 4.4. so the error comes。 the error is

./classfier/classfier-hash.h:120 error: cast from void* to int loss pression

I know this error  occur because of the type changed. I want to know whether the reason of this error is the version is modified by me. if yes,whether there are some patch filed to used.

Comment: Why use a *very* old version of Ubuntu? On later versions ns2 is [available in the repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ns2).

Comment: if u want to install ns2 I direct u to one as I can say complete page which he install ns2 on the 12.04 read all of this and solve your problem in installing that for ever but you should be patient enough some at first are not related. http://lqcdn.thequestionsnetwork.net/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns2-version-2-34-is-too-old-wpan-802-15-4-a-4175499373/

Comment: @Biffen Thank you for your suggestion. I had to use this version for some reason.